# How to hide Data in Crystal Report if data does not meet

Tags: c#, crystal-reports-2010

I am using an `if-then` conditional in a Crystal Reports formula.  I want to display just one record in report based on the results of the conditional.  For example:

```
if(....)="H" then "Habbits" or if(.....)="I" then "Indoor"
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to show data like Habbit, Indoor etc based on condition.
Follow these steps If I am correct in guessing the question:

1. Create a new formula field, and add the condition in the same.

   ```
   stringvar nameofvar:="";
   if(....)="H" then nameofvar:="Habbits" 
   else if(.....)="I" then nameofvar:="Indoor"

   //If there is a problem in this formula then specify
   ```
2. Drag the formula field from field explorer to the area on the report where you want it to show.